# Is logical subscription replicated (as all other data) by streaming replication in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Assuming to have 3 PostgreSQL 12 nodes: A,B,C.

1. A node contains dataset and it's a logical publisher.
2. B node doesn't contain data but has same schema and tables as node A. B node is logical subscriber to A.

If C node is configured as streaming replica of B - will logical subscription be replicated from B to C? Should it start another logical subscription with A as publisher and C as subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscription will be replicated from B to C, but no logical replication will take place. You cannot apply any logical replication changes to C, since it is read-only, and it isn't necessary, because all logical replication changes applied to B will be replicated to C anyway.